# Accessing variables from another class when importing a .ccbi file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I know this topic is covered in a hundred posts here, but I'm having a lot of trouble with this particular instance and cannot figure it out.

Basically, I'm using Spritebuilder to import sprites/nodes into my game. I import a sprite of some specific class in the body of the `GameScene` class, but I want to be able to define a variable inside of my sprite class, and then edit it from the `GameScene` class. For example, if my sprite collects a coin inside the GameScene, I want to change the speed of my sprite inside of the `update` method in the sprite class.

Below is my code, but unfortunately it isn't working. The variable `increaseY` and `increaseX` do not appear to be available in my `GameScene` class. I know this is because I didn't instantiate the `Penguin` class properly, but I don't know how to properly create an instance of this class while simultaneously importing the .ccbi file of it. The problem line is commented on and has a bunch of ****** next to it to easily find it. It's in `GameScene.m`. I really appreciate the help, been stuck on this for several hours.

**Penguin.h**

```
#import "CCSprite.h"

@interface Penguin : CCSprite

{
    float xPosition;
    float yPosition;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) float increaseY;
@property (nonatomic,assign) float increaseX;


@end
```

**Penguin.m**

```
#import "Penguin.h"

@implementation Penguin

@synthesize increaseX;
@synthesize increaseY;


- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        CCLOG(@"Penguin created");
    }

    return self;

}

-(void) update:(CCTime)delta
{
    self.position = ccp(self.position.x + increaseX,self.position.y + increaseY);
}

@end
```

**GameScene.h**

```
#import "CCNode.h"

@interface GameScene : CCNode

@end
```

**GameScene.m**

```
#import "GameScene.h"
#import "Penguin.h"

@implementation GameScene

{
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
    CCNode *_catapultArm;
    CCNode *_levelNode;
    CCNode *_contentNode;

}

// is called when CCB file has completed loading
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {

    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    CCScene *level = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Levels/Level1"];
    [_levelNode addChild:level];
}

// called on every touch in this scene
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self launchPenguin];
}

- (void)launchPenguin {
    // loads the Penguin.ccb we have set up in Spritebuilder
    CCNode* penguin = [CCBReader load:@"Penguin"];
    penguin.position = ccpAdd(_catapultArm.position, ccp(16, 50));
    [_physicsNode addChild:penguin];

    //THE FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT WORK********************************
    penguin.increaseY = 1;
    // Gives Error------Property "increaseX" not found on object of type "CCNode *"

    self.position = ccp(0, 0);
    CCActionFollow *follow = [CCActionFollow actionWithTarget:penguin worldBoundary:self.boundingBox];
    [_contentNode runAction:follow];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line:

```
CCNode* penguin = [CCBReader load:@"Penguin"];
```

To this line:

```
Penguin* penguin = (Penguin*)[CCBReader load:@"Penguin"];
```

In the old line you were using the compiler was giving you an error because the `CCNode` class does not have a property called `increaseX`. `increaseX` is part of the `Penguin` class. If you want to access properties of the `Penguin` class you need to use a cast and let the compiler know, that what you are loading using the `CCBReader` is actually a `Penguin` instance.